# Is there a way to query when I contributed to a pull request with submitting review with github-api v3 Search API?

Tags: github-api

I'm trying to query GitHub Search API to fetch my contributions that are made by submitting reviews on pull requests.

On my profile page on GitHub, there's "Contribution Activity" and there's a pane "Reviewed X pull requests in Y repositories" in it. When I expand it, I see a list of my contributions made by review submitting, and it includes information such as "when I made the contribution". I confirmed this is not the date of pull request creaqted, merged, updated.

Is there a way to fetch "when I made the review contribution" via GitHub Search API?

[reviewed date on profile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkP4q.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GraphQL Api v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) and filter the reviews by author for each pull request from the search query :

```graphql
{
  search(query: "reviewed-by:eps1lon is:pr updated:2019-01-01..2019-01-31", type: ISSUE, first: 100) {
    issueCount
      nodes {
        ... on PullRequest {
          repository {
            nameWithOwner
          }
          number
          reviews(author: "eps1lon", last: 1) {
            nodes {
              createdAt
              lastEditedAt
              publishedAt
              body
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20search(query%3A%20%22reviewed-by%3Aeps1lon%20is%3Apr%20updated%3A2019-01-01..2019-01-31%22%2C%20type%3A%20ISSUE%2C%20first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20issueCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20PullRequest%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nameWithOwner%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20number%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reviews(author%3A%20%22eps1lon%22%2C%20last%3A%201)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createdAt%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lastEditedAt%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20publishedAt%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20body%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

You will need to [iterate over all the results](https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/) if there is more than 100 results

To format your result & sort by date you can use a json parser like [jq](/questions/tagged/jq). Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) & [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) :

```bash
user=eps1lon
date_range=2019-01-01..2019-01-31
token=YOUR_TOKEN

curl -s -H "Authorization: bearer $token" -d '
{
    "query": "query {search(query: \"reviewed-by:'"$user"' is:pr updated:'"$date_range"'\", type: ISSUE, first: 100) {issueCount nodes {... on PullRequest {repository {nameWithOwner}number reviews(author: '"$user"', last: 1) {nodes {createdAt lastEditedAt publishedAt body}}}}}}"
}
' https://api.github.com/graphql | \
  jq '[ 
        .data.search.nodes[] | 
        {
            repo:.repository.nameWithOwner, 
            number:.number, 
            createdAt:.reviews.nodes[0].createdAt, 
            publishedAt:.reviews.nodes[0].publishedAt,
            lastEditedAt: .reviews.nodes[0].lastEditedAt
        } | 
        select (.createdAt >= "2019-01-01") ] | 
        sort_by(.createdAt) | 
        reverse'
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! But your query is filtered by "pull requests that are updated in specified term". Making contribution by reviewing is not reflected to updated date of pull request. I'd like to filter pull requests by "making contribution by review by me in specified term".